# WebKit API for DOM

Tags: c++, browser, webkit, webbrowser-control

Does WebKit expose an API for working directly with its DOM? I'm looking for a class like HtmlElement that can be used to build/traverse trees of HTML content.

I'm trying to host WebKit as a web browser control in a desktop application, and would prefer a direct API rather than going through COM.  Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you merge this with the other thread of yours i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563996/gecko-api-for-dom? Change the heading, to [X API for DOM].

Comment: I figured people are either experts on Gecko or WebKit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using QT/WebKit (at least version 4.6) it's now possible to access the DOM of the loaded document.

[QtWebKit Module reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit.html)

[DOM Traversal Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/webkit-domtraversal.html)

Comment: I've updated the URL, and added a direct link to sample code, thanks.

Comment: The links are dead again, sorry. Here's the GTK version: https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Following URL has some interesting answer to you.

[Where is WebKIT API?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=901305)

Comment: by taking the source code and compiling it, of course - how else?  sorry, but this is a silly question, jen :)

Answer (score 1):

you have a limited number of options, via the various DOM wrappers.  the PyWebkitQt one is truly rubbish; the Objective-C one is only available on MacOSX (and is again limited and incomplete); the COM one is only available on windows; the GObject one is *still* under development even though the first version that was created in 2008 was superior and more feature-complete than what's actually now in webkit mainline source code; there are also some c++ bindings but i have not evaluated them.  and then of course there's also the Javascript bindings and the google V8 javascript bindings (yes they're separate) but those are only available "in-browser".

that pretty much leaves the pythonwebkit project - http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit - as the only non-javascript-based DOM manipulation API that actually aims for full de-facto standards compliance, making python truly a peer of javascript when it comes to DOM manipulation.